# Memory management for a .NET (wpf) application

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, memory-management

An analysis of the performance of our application showed that the CPU usage was peaking at times when memory had to be allocated by the .NET memory management.

There was an (enormous) amount of memory just free but it was not claimed by the application, it searched for free space in its already claimed portion of memory.

Is it possible to configure an application to claim more memory when possible?
Is this perhaps related to the fact that the application is hosted under Citrix?

Comment: What do you mean by 'There was an enormous amount of memory just free?' Do you mean it's actually released, i.e. via `VirtualFree`, or did GC just compact one of the SOH? Also, is your slow allocation on the LOH or SOH?

Comment: The performance counters showed that on the Citrix server maximally ca. 20% of the Citrix memory was in use by the process. I wonder why the process does not use e.g. 30-40%? Unfortunately the LOH/SOH is not in these performance data.

Comment: Is it a 32 bit or 64 bit process? Could you give the actual numbers in the question? This will help in understanding which limits you might be hitting.

Answer (score 1):

Windows applications can't grow indefinitely, no matter how much free memory the system has.

You can read about the actual limits here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx#memory_limits

And extra information about the issue here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483475/Memory-Limits-in-a-NET-Process

If an application gets too close to its limit, it'll start spinning the Garbage Collector everytime it needs to claim new memory, to avoid running out of space and crashing with an OutOfMemoryException. This extra effort to release and claim memory at the same time has a great negative effect on performance, either.

At which point does your application stop claiming new memory? Close to 1 Gb? 2 Gb? 64 bit applications are able to use larger amounts of memory, but it may not be an option...